# How do I insert a custom form into a Drupal node view and process the node's data on submission?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-fapi

We are importing our sales orders from our accounting system into a Drupal 6 site.

We setup a content type called orders.

I would like to build a shipping module for our shipping provider (no there isnt already one).

I understand how to build "block" modules and "content" modules.

What is the best approach to build a module that would appear at the bottom of our order nodes that presents a form they need to complete (which in turn would process the shipping)

If possible I would like to do this without creating a different content type

Comment: Also I am aware of Ubercart with shipping modules etc and we will be using it at some point but it doesnt really fit with what is required at the moment

Comment: may i know about "block" modules and "content" modules please

Comment: So Im guessing I can use hook_nodeapi but not sure how I can add a new form to the output of the node

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to attach a custom form to every node, first you need (in your module) to:

- write the function that will build the form (see: [Generating Forms](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/6)). If this function will display node-related data according to the node that's currently being viewed, then you'll probably want to pass the *nid* or the whole `$node` as an argument.

Then you have to decide how you want to go about inserting the form into the node page (or however it is that the node is being viewed), and there's a couple of ways to go about it, including:

1. Implementing [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) and within the "view" operation (i.e `$op == 'view'`) you could get your form and add it to `$node->content`.
2. Adding the form as a template variable (see: [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6), you would do a `MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars)`) so you can put it wherever you want in your custom node.tpl.php.

I guess there are more ways to go about it (having your module generate a block with the form in it, etc.), it depends on what you specifically need.

Whichever you choose, the way you get the markup for your custom form is:

```
<?php
// something like this for hook_nodeapi() way.
$node->content['body']['value']] .= drupal_get_form('my_custom_form_generating_function', $node);
// or something like this for the hook_preprocess_node() way.
$vars['my_custom_form'] = drupal_get_form('my_custom_form_generating_function', $vars['node']);
```

If your form-generating function will indeed accept the $node as a parameter, then you'll need to either use PHP's [func_get_args()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) or explicitly declare the `$node` argument in the signature:

```
<?php
function my_custom_form_generating_function($form_state, $node) { }
```

And to be clear:

> ...to build a module *that would appear at* the bottom of our...

Drupal modules are not things that "appear". Modules are extensions that provide additional **functionality** to your Drupal site. They can implement **hooks** which may or may not end up generating markup that will "appear" on you site.

Regarding "content modules" and "block modules": Even though I've seen the term "*node* module" to refer to modules that provide new content types, any module can implement any hook, and thus provide blocks, content types, etc.